# How to manage methods\variables caller class?

Tags: object, dialog, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

in class standard class **Dialog** exist an **Object** declare (in *classDeclaration*)

```
Object caller;
```

In this class I'm able to get the caller class name. For example:

```
if (caller.name() == classStr(MyCallerClass) )
{
     // manage-pass variable in caller class
}
```

If I catch in the IF, I want to pass a parameter in *parm* method in to  *MyCallerClass*.

How I can pass a simple parameter? For example:

```
if (caller.name() == classStr(MyCallerClass) )
{
     // MyCallerClass.myParmMethod(parameter);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call the method:

```
if (caller.name() == classStr(MyCallerClass))
    caller.myParmMethod('abc');
```

As `caller` is of type `Object` the compiler accepts any method name, it uses [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).
A run time error happens if caller does not have the method.

That said, you should *not* change the standard `Dialog` class.
You might extend the class, though this is unlikely to be the right thing.

What you *should* do depends on information you do not give.

Comment: Thanks @Jan B. Kjeldsen. Nice advice.

Answer (score 1):

The correct & safe way is:

```
   MyCallerClass myCalss;

   if (caller && classidget(caller) == classnum(MyCallerClass))
   {
      myClass = caller;
      myClass.myParmMethod('abc');
   }
```

See examples in form.init methods.

Comment: Hi @mazzy nice advice. Thanks!